# Problem with conditions and integrals in Fortran

Tags: if-statement, fortran, integral

I was given a task to program a task in Fortran and I can’t understand where my errors are and how to correct them. Initially, the files "A(1 2 3 2 1)", "B(1 2 3 2 1)", "T(2 2 2 2 2)", and limits from a to b "(-2 -1 0 1 2)" ;"T = 2" ;"M = 3"; Y = 5". Bottom line, you need to display all R.
It is advisable that the line and its problem be directly indicated to me, because I am a rather stupid person.
I will be sincerely grateful [taskex1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6Crz.jpg) [taskex2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKogW.jpg) [taskex3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TB3p3.jpg)

```
All errors and warnings:
gfortran -Wall -c 

2.f90:2:2:
    2 |         dimension A(5), A1(5), B(5), B1(5), T(5), T1(5), H(5), D(5), V(5), X(5), CC(5), CC1(5)
      |         1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]

2.f90:31:2:
   31 |                 111 continue
      |         1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]

2.f90:32:2:
   32 |                 if ((A(i)/B(i)).le.T(i)) then
      |         1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]

2.f90:33:2:
   33 |                         A1(i) = A(i)
      |         1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]
2.f90:34:2:
   34 |                         B1(i) = B(i)
      |         1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]

2.f90:35:2:
   35 |                         T1(i) = T(i)
      |         1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]
2.f90:36:2:
   36 |                 else
      |         1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]

2.f90:37:2:
   37 |                         T1(i) = T(i)
      |         1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]

2.f90:38:2:
   38 |                         B1(i) = B(i)
      |         1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]

2.f90:39:2:
   39 |                         A1(i) = B1(i) * T1(i)
      |         1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]

2.f90:40:2:
   40 |                 endif
      |         1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]

2.f90:43:2:
   43 |                 n=size(X)
      |         1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]

2.f90:44:2:
   44 |                 S=0.0
      |         1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]

2.f90:45:2:
   45 |                 do i=1, n-1
      |         1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]

2.f90:45:13:
   16 |     do i = 1, 5
      |               2
......
   45 |                 do i=1, n-1
      |                           1
Error: Variable 'i' at (1) cannot be redefined inside loop beginning at (2)

2.f90:46:2:
   46 |                 S1=S
      |         1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]

2.f90:47:2:
   47 |                 S=S+0.5*(X(i+1)-X(i))*(A1(i+1)+A1(i))
      |         1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]

2.f90:48:2:
   48 |                 V(i)=S1
      |         1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]

2.f90:49:2:
   49 |                 end do
      |         1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]

2.f90:50:2:
   50 |                 V(n)=S
      |         1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]

2.f90:53:2:
   53 |                 n=size(X)
      |         1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]

2.f90:54:2:
   54 |                 CC(i) = (1/12.) * (B1(i))**3
      |         1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]

2.f90:55:2:
   55 |                 S=0.0
      |         1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]

2.f90:56:2:
   56 |                 do i=1, n-1
      |         1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]

2.f90:56:13:
   16 |     do i = 1, 5
      |               2
......
   56 |                 do i=1, n-1
      |                           1
Error: Variable 'i' at (1) cannot be redefined inside loop beginning at (2)

2.f90:57:2:
   57 |                 S1=S
      |         1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]

2.f90:58:2:
   58 |                 S=S+0.5*(X(i+1)-X(i))*(CC(i+1)+CC(i))
      |         1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]

2.f90:59:2:
   59 |                 H(i)=S1
      |         1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]

2.f90:60:2:
   60 |                 end do
      |         1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]

2.f90:61:2:
   61 |                 H(n)=S * (1/V(n))
      |         1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]

2.f90:64:2:
   64 |                 n=size(X)
      |         1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]

2.f90:65:2:
   65 |                 CC1(i) = ((-T1(i))/2.) * A1(i)
      |         1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]

2.f90:66:2:
   66 |                 S=0.0
      |         1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]

2.f90:67:2:
   67 |                 do i=1, n-1
      |         1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]

2.f90:67:13:
   16 |     do i = 1, 5
      |               2
......
   67 |                 do i=1, n-1
      |                           1
Error: Variable 'i' at (1) cannot be redefined inside loop beginning at (2)

2.f90:68:2:
   68 |                 S1=S
      |         1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]

2.f90:69:2:
   69 |                 S=S+0.5*(X(i+1)-X(i))*(CC1(i+1)+CC1(i))
      |         1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]

2.f90:70:2:
   70 |                 D(i)=S1
      |         1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]

2.f90:71:2:
   71 |                 end do
      |         1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]

2.f90:72:2:
   72 |                 D(n)=S * (1/V(n)) + T
      |         1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]

2.f90:75:2:
   75 |                 G = D(n) + H(n) + M
      |         1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]

2.f90:76:2:
   76 |                 O1 = G - T
      |         1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]

2.f90:79:2:
   79 |                 do i = X(1),X(5)
      |         1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]

2.f90:79:18:
   16 |     do i = 1, 5
      |               2
......
   79 |                 do i = X(1),X(5)
      |                                1
Error: Variable 'i' at (1) cannot be redefined inside loop beginning at (2)

2.f90:80:2:
   80 |                 K1(i) = ((sin(L *(B1(i)/2.)))/(L*B1(i))/2.) * (((1+L*T1(i)) * e ** (-L*T1(i) - 1)) / ((L**2) * T1(i)))
      |         1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]

2.f90:81:2:
   81 |                 end do
      |         1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]

2.f90:84:2:
   84 |                 do i = X(1),X(5)
      |         1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]

2.f90:84:18:
   16 |     do i = 1, 5
      |               2
......
   84 |                 do i = X(1),X(5)
      |                                1
Error: Variable 'i' at (1) cannot be redefined inside loop beginning at (2)

2.f90:85:2:
   85 |                 K2(i) = (-((e ** (-L*T1(i) - 1)) / ((L**2) * T1(i))))* (cos(L*(B1(i)/2.)) - ((sin(L*(B1(i)/2.)))/(L*(B1(i)/2.))))
      |         1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]

2.f90:86:2:
   86 |                 end do
      |         1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]

2.f90:89:2:
   89 |                 do i = X(1),X(5)
      |         1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]

2.f90:89:18:
   16 |     do i = 1, 5
      |               2
......
   89 |                 do i = X(1),X(5)
      |                                1
Error: Variable 'i' at (1) cannot be redefined inside loop beginning at (2)

2.f90:90:2:
   90 |                 F1(i) = -((1 - (e**(-L*T1(i))))/(L*T1(i))) * ((sin(L*(B1(i)/2.)))/((L*B1(i))/2.))
      |         1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]

2.f90:91:2:
   91 |                 end do
      |         1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]

2.f90:94:2:
   94 |                 do i = X(1),X(5)
      |         1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]

2.f90:94:18:
   16 |     do i = 1, 5
      |               2
......
   94 |                 do i = X(1),X(5)
      |                                1
Error: Variable 'i' at (1) cannot be redefined inside loop beginning at (2)

2.f90:95:2:
   95 |                 if (A1(i) .eq. 0 .and. B1(i) .eq. 0) then
      |         1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]

2.f90:96:2:
   96 |                 C(i) = 0
      |         1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]

2.f90:97:2:
   97 |                 else
      |         1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]

2.f90:98:2:
   98 |                         C(i) = A1(i) * (K1(i) + K2(i) + F1(i) * O1)
      |         1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]

2.f90:99:2:
   99 |                 endif
      |         1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]

2.f90:100:2:
  100 |                 end do
      |         1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]

2.f90:103:2:
  103 |                 do i = X(1),X(5)
      |         1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]

2.f90:103:18:
   16 |     do i = 1, 5
      |               2
......
  103 |                 do i = X(1),X(5)
      |                                1
Error: Variable 'i' at (1) cannot be redefined inside loop beginning at (2)

2.f90:104:2:
  104 |                 n=size(X)
      |         1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]

2.f90:105:2:
  105 |                 S=0.0
      |         1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]

2.f90:106:2:
  106 |                 do i=1, n-1
      |         1

Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]

2.f90:106:13:
  103 |                 do i = X(1),X(5)
      |                                2
......
  106 |                 do i=1, n-1
      |                           1

Error: Variable 'i' at (1) cannot be redefined inside loop beginning at (2)

2.f90:107:2:
  107 |                 S1=S
      |         1

Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]

2.f90:108:2:
  108 |                 S=S+0.5*(X(i+1)-X(i))*(C(i+1)+C(i))
      |         1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]

2.f90:109:2:
  109 |                 R(i)=S1
      |         1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]

2.f90:110:2:
  110 |                 end do
      |         1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]

2.f90:111:2:
  111 |                 R(n)=abs(S / (V(n) * M))
      |         1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]

2.f90:112:2:
  112 |                 end do
      |         1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]

2.f90:113:2:
  113 |                 print *, R
      |         1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]

2.f90:114:2:
  114 |         end do
      |         1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]

2.f90:31:5:
   31 |                 111 continue
      |                   1
Warning: Label 111 at (1) defined but not used [-Wunused-label]

2.f90:72:2:
   72 |                 D(n)=S * (1/V(n)) + T
      |         1
Error: Incompatible ranks 0 and 1 in assignment at (1)

2.f90:76:2:
   76 |                 O1 = G - T
      |         1
Error: Incompatible ranks 0 and 1 in assignment at (1)
2.f90:79:8:
   79 |                 do i = X(1),X(5)
      |                      1
Warning: Deleted feature: Start expression in DO loop at (1) must be integer

2.f90:79:14:
   79 |                 do i = X(1),X(5)
      |                            1
Warning: Deleted feature: End expression in DO loop at (1) must be integer

2.f90:79:8:
   79 |                 do i = X(1),X(5)
      |                      1
Warning: Possible change of value in conversion from REAL(4) to INTEGER(4) at (1) [-Wconversion]

2.f90:79:14:
   79 |                 do i = X(1),X(5)
      |                            1
Warning: Possible change of value in conversion from REAL(4) to INTEGER(4) at (1) [-Wconversion]

2.f90:84:8:
   84 |                 do i = X(1),X(5)
      |                      1
Warning: Deleted feature: Start expression in DO loop at (1) must be integer

2.f90:84:14:
   84 |                 do i = X(1),X(5)
      |                            1
Warning: Deleted feature: End expression in DO loop at (1) must be integer

2.f90:84:8:
   84 |                 do i = X(1),X(5)
      |                      1
Warning: Possible change of value in conversion from REAL(4) to INTEGER(4) at (1) [-Wconversion]

2.f90:84:14:
   84 |                 do i = X(1),X(5)
      |                            1
Warning: Possible change of value in conversion from REAL(4) to INTEGER(4) at (1) [-Wconversion]

2.f90:89:8:
   89 |                 do i = X(1),X(5)
      |                      1
Warning: Deleted feature: Start expression in DO loop at (1) must be integer

2.f90:89:14:
   89 |                 do i = X(1),X(5)
      |                            1
Warning: Deleted feature: End expression in DO loop at (1) must be integer

2.f90:89:8:
   89 |                 do i = X(1),X(5)
      |                      1
Warning: Possible change of value in conversion from REAL(4) to INTEGER(4) at (1) [-Wconversion]

2.f90:89:14:
   89 |                 do i = X(1),X(5)
      |                            1
Warning: Possible change of value in conversion from REAL(4) to INTEGER(4) at (1) [-Wconversion]

2.f90:94:8:
   94 |                 do i = X(1),X(5)
      |                      1
Warning: Deleted feature: Start expression in DO loop at (1) must be integer

2.f90:94:14:
   94 |                 do i = X(1),X(5)
      |                            1
Warning: Deleted feature: End expression in DO loop at (1) must be integer

2.f90:94:8:
   94 |                 do i = X(1),X(5)
      |                      1
Warning: Possible change of value in conversion from REAL(4) to INTEGER(4) at (1) [-Wconversion]

2.f90:94:14:
   94 |                 do i = X(1),X(5)
      |                            1
Warning: Possible change of value in conversion from REAL(4) to INTEGER(4) at (1) [-Wconversion]

2.f90:103:8:
  103 |                 do i = X(1),X(5)
      |                      1
Warning: Deleted feature: Start expression in DO loop at (1) must be integer

2.f90:103:14:
  103 |                 do i = X(1),X(5)
      |                            1
Warning: Deleted feature: End expression in DO loop at (1) must be integer

2.f90:103:8:
  103 |                 do i = X(1),X(5)
      |                      1
Warning: Possible change of value in conversion from REAL(4) to INTEGER(4) at (1) [-Wconversion]

2.f90:103:14:
  103 |                 do i = X(1),X(5)
      |                            1
Warning: Possible change of value in conversion from REAL(4) to INTEGER(4) at (1) [-Wconversion]

2.f90:47:13:
   16 |     do i = 1, 5
      |               2
......
   47 |                 S=S+0.5*(X(i+1)-X(i))*(A1(i+1)+A1(i))
      |                           1
Warning: Array reference at (1) out of bounds (6 > 5) in loop beginning at (2)

2.f90:47:28:
   16 |     do i = 1, 5
      |               2
......
   47 |                 S=S+0.5*(X(i+1)-X(i))*(A1(i+1)+A1(i))
      |                                          1
Warning: Array reference at (1) out of bounds (6 > 5) in loop beginning at (2)

2.f90:58:13:
   16 |     do i = 1, 5
      |               2
......
   58 |                 S=S+0.5*(X(i+1)-X(i))*(CC(i+1)+CC(i))
      |                           1
Warning: Array reference at (1) out of bounds (6 > 5) in loop beginning at (2)

2.f90:58:28:
   16 |     do i = 1, 5
      |               2
......
   58 |                 S=S+0.5*(X(i+1)-X(i))*(CC(i+1)+CC(i))
      |                                          1
Warning: Array reference at (1) out of bounds (6 > 5) in loop beginning at (2)

2.f90:69:13:
   16 |     do i = 1, 5
      |               2
......
   69 |                 S=S+0.5*(X(i+1)-X(i))*(CC1(i+1)+CC1(i))
      |                           1
Warning: Array reference at (1) out of bounds (6 > 5) in loop beginning at (2)

2.f90:69:29:
   16 |     do i = 1, 5
      |               2
......
   69 |                 S=S+0.5*(X(i+1)-X(i))*(CC1(i+1)+CC1(i))
      |                                           1
Warning: Array reference at (1) out of bounds (6 > 5) in loop beginning at (2)

2.f90:108:13:
   16 |     do i = 1, 5
      |               2
......
  108 |                 S=S+0.5*(X(i+1)-X(i))*(C(i+1)+C(i))
      |                           1
Warning: Array reference at (1) out of bounds (6 > 5) in loop beginning at (2)
```

```
    real :: A(1:5), A1(1:5), B(1:5),B1(1:5),T(1:5),T1(1:5),H(1:5),D(1:5),V(1:5),X(1:5),CC(1:5),CC1(1:5),T,G,M,L,Y,O1,K1,K2,F1,R,C,a,b,S,S1,e
    integer :: i,n
    open(1, file = 'A.txt')
    open(2, file = 'B.txt')
    open(3, file = 'T.txt')
    open(4, file = 'ab.txt')
    T = 2
    M = 3
    Y = 5
    L = (Y**2)/9.81
    e = 2.718
    
    !conditions
do i = 1,5
     
        read (1,*) A
        read (2,*) B
        read (3,*) T
        read (4,*) X
    
        if (A(i).gt.0 .and. B(i).gt.0) go to 111
        else
            A1(i) = 0
            B1(i) = 0
            T1(i) = 0
        endif
        111 continue    
        if ((A(i)/B(i)).le.T(i)) then
            A1(i) = A(i)
            B1(i) = B(i)
            T1(i) = T(i)
        else
            T1(i) = T(i)
            B1(i) = B(i)
            A1(i) = B1(i) * T1(i)
        endif
        
        !V
        n=size(X)
        S=0.0
        do i=1, n-1
        S1=S
        S=S+0.5*(X(i+1)-X(i))*(A1(i+1)+A1(i))
        V(i)=S1
        end do
        V(n)=S
        
        !H
        n=size(X)
        CC(i) = (1/12.) * (B1(i))**3
        S=0.0
        do i=1, n-1
        S1=S
        S=S+0.5*(X(i+1)-X(i))*(CC(i+1)+CC(i))
        H(i)=S1
        end do
        H(n)=S * (1/V(n))
        
        !D
        n=size(X)
        CC1(i) = ((-T1(i))/2.) * A1(i)
        S=0.0
        do i=1, n-1
        S1=S
        S=S+0.5*(X(i+1)-X(i))*(CC1(i+1)+CC1(i))
        D(i)=S1
        end do
        D(n)=S * (1/V(n)) + T
        
        !G и O1
        G = D(n) + H(n) + M
        O1 = G - T
        
        !K1
        do i = X(1),X(5)
        K1(i) = ((sin(L *(B1(i)/2.)))/(L*B1(i))/2.) * (((1+L*T1(i)) * e ** (-L*T1(i) - 1)) / ((L**2) * T1(i)))
        end do
        
        !K2
        do i = X(1),X(5)
        K2(i) = (-((e ** (-L*T1(i) - 1)) / ((L**2) * T1(i))))* (cos(L*(B1(i)/2.)) - ((sin(L*(B1(i)/2.)))/(L*(B1(i)/2.))))
        end do
        
        !F1
        do i = X(1),X(5)
        F1(i) = -((1 - (e**(-L*T1(i))))/(L*T1(i))) * ((sin(L*(B1(i)/2.)))/((L*B1(i))/2.))
        end do
        
        !C
        do i = X(1),X(5)
        if (A1(i) .eq. 0 .and. B1(i) .eq. 0) then
        C(i) = 0
        else
            C(i) = A1(i) * (K1(i) + K2(i) + F1(i) * O1)
        endif
        end do
        
        !R
        do i = X(1),X(5)
        n=size(X)
        S=0.0
        do i=1, n-1
        S1=S
        S=S+0.5*(X(i+1)-X(i))*(C(i+1)+C(i))
        R(i)=S1
        end do
        R(n)=abs(S / (V(n) * M))
        end do
        print *, R
end do
```

Comment: We also have no idea where your errors are. You do not show any. Copy and paste your error mesages and the commands that produced them. See [ask] and [mre].

Comment: You have a loop that uses `i` as the iteration variable inside another loop that also uses `i` as the iteration variable. That is not allowed. Alsi, just do not use tabs. Set your text editor to use spaces when you hit the tab key on the keyboard.