# Problem with assigning one last value to an integral in Fortran

Tags: fortran, integral

I asked a question about this code before and here is a link to it:
[Problem with conditions and integrals in Fortran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78077568/problem-with-conditions-and-integrals-in-fortran)

But I decided to rewrite it and make it more convenient, but the problem is that for further calculations I need the value of V, H, D to take on the value of one digit. But for me it takes 5, and they are different when I restart, although the final number I need is the same.
I need that after everything, the value 'V' takes only the value = 8, and not everything. Exactly the same with D, H.

I entered print *, V and saw what it outputs after the entire

```
  value:1;2.5;4;5.5;8;
```

Or

```
Random number;Random number;Random number;Random number;8
```

And it turns out that I need 'V' to be only = 8 after calculations

Code:

```
    dimension A1(5), B1(5),  T1(5), D(5), OOO(5), HH(5),DD(5)
    real :: T, M, L, Y, a, b, e, V, H
    real A(5) /1,2,3,2,1/
    real B(5) /1,2,3,2,1/
    real T(5) /2,2,2,2,2/
    real X(5) /-2,-1,0,1,2/
    integer :: i
    T = 2
    M = 3.0
    Y = 5
    L = (Y**2) / 9.81
    e = 2.718
    KN = 5
     do i = 1, 5

      if (A(i) > 0 .and. B(i) > 0) then 
       go to 123
      else
       A1(i) = 0
       B1(i) = 0
       T1(i) = 0
      endif
      123 if ((A(i)/B(i)) <= T(i)) then
           A1(i) = A(i)
           B1(i) = B(i)
           T1(i) = A(i)/B(i)
          else
           B1(i) = B(i)
           T1(i) = T(i)
           A1(i) = B1(i) * T1(i)
          endif
       
      !V
      call VV(X, A, OOO,V)
      print *, V
      !H
      HH(i) = (1.0/12.0)* B1(i)**3
      call VV(X, HH, OOO,HHH)
      H = HHH * (1.0/V)
   
      !D
      DD(i) = ((-T1(i))/2.0) * A1(i)
      call VV(X,A,OOO,DDD)
      D = (DDD * (1.0/V)) + T
   
   
     end do
 
    end program F
    !Integral
    subroutine VV(X, Y, IY,O)
    real, intent(in):: X(1:5), Y(1:5)
    real :: IY(1:5), S, S1, O
    integer:: i, n
      n=size(X)
      S=0.0
      do i=1, n-1
        S1=S
        S=S+0.5*(X(i+1)-X(i))*(Y(i+1)+Y(i))
        IY(i)=S1
      end do
      IY(n)=S
      O = IY(n)
      return
    end subroutine VV
```

Comment: Please show an example of the output you see and explain what output you expect instead. Please understand that without your input files we have no chance to test the code. Can you make a [mcve] that would not need the input files or just a very simple one that you can copy and paste into your question? Definitely try to compile and run your code with all debugging flags enabled, like `gfortran -g -fbacktrace -fcheck=all -Wall`.

Comment: @Vladimir F Героям слава
I rewrote it so that there was no input data and wrote what the results were and what exactly was needed
Used in properties: **-g -fbacktrace -fcheck=all -Wall**. 
Nothing has changed

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that "print *, V" was in the loop

Problem solved